# Is my TOR installation compromised?

Tags: relays

Firstly, I am not an Internet or TOR expert I have just started exploring it. BUT after using it OK for a couple of months I have recently noticed what to me is suspicious/odd. Nowadays when ever I use TOR the first node is always the same IP in France. To me that hardly seems secure. This first node happens even if I choose new circuit or new identity several times. It also happens if I use my VPN first (and change the server location several times (eg India Sweden UK)). I didn't use TOR for over 2 weeks connected again today and sure enough the same first node IP. To me always going to the same first node seems very odd as I would have thought one of the benefits of TOR would be random circuits Do I have a problem or am I being paranoid?

Comment: What you're seeing is expected and part of the design. Changing the entry node each time you create a circuit is actually less secure.